# Stop processing more rules when needed

Tags: vba, outlook

Using Outlook 2010, I want to add "stop processing more rules" to a rule.

I have a rule defined using the normal rules interface in Outlook. That rule is one of many rules, all of which have "stop processing more rules" set except for this one. The rule runs a script. This one does not have "stop processing more rules". Until the script is run I don't know if I want to stop processing more rules. I don't want to change this rule (or any rule) in VBA, just decide in the VBA script whether to stop processing more rules.

Code I'm using (edited down a bit)

```
Public Sub checkforvalidfiletype(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olkAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim orule As Outlook.Rules
    Dim oRuleAction As Outlook.RuleAction
    'Check each attachment
    Stop
    For Each olkAtt In Item.Attachments
        'If the attachment's file name ends with .xls .csv or .xlsx
        If Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 4) = ".xls" Or Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 4) = ".csv" Or Right(LCase(olkAtt.FileName), 5) = ".xlsx" Then
            'then assign it to the Unknown .xls .xlxs or .csv to be processed category
            Item.Categories = "Unknown .xls .xlxs or .csv to be processed"
            Item.Save
            'and stop processing more rules
            Set oRuleAction = orule.Actions.Stop
            With oRuleAction
                .Enabled = True
            End With
            'No need to check any of this message's remaining attachments (just one valid attachment is enough for us to want to know about it)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set olkAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

I get a run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set error, on the `Set oRuleAction = orule.Actions.Stop` line. (I have the right object library referenced.)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out yourself by now. Just from what you've posted, the oRule object is not set, and you probably want Rules object from which you'll set the Rule object ...

```
Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules
Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule
```

Illustrative similar code at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867254(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: OK, but would that not just alter the existing rule to include the "stop processing more rules" action. If so that is not what I want to do, I want to just stop processing more rules on this particular occasion, leaving the existing rule (and all the other rules in fact) unchanged?

Comment: Maybe I should make this clearer as perhaps I'm not explaining myself very well. I have a rule defined using the normal rules interface in outlook (i.e not in VBA). That rule is one of many rules, all of which have "stop processing more rules" set except for this one. The rule just runs a script.  The reason this one does not have "stop processing more rules" set is because until the script is run I don't know if I want to stop processing more rules or not. I don't want to change this rule (or any rule) in VBA, just decide in the VBA script whether to stop processing more rules or not.

Comment: I've got a project milestone I need to meet by close of business today, so I have to be brief -- apologies -- but my suggestion responds to your statement "I then get a run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set error, on the Set oRuleAction = orule.Actions.Stop line" ... without seeing all of your code, that typically would indicate that "oRule" has not been set ... and to set an oRule, you would need to first set to the "collection" of all rules, then set oRule to the specific rule you want to act upon ... hope this helps!

Comment: after setting colRules as needed (example in original answer) then "set oRule = colRules.Item("<your item name>") ... if it doesn't work sorry couldn't be more help.

Comment: Thank-you for the help so far, but it doesn't work. I've put in the collection of rules code and shown the code below